# (actionscript3) How I can add virtual buttons for an embedded flash game in Android AIR?

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I'm new to AS3 and I'm actually trying to convert a complicated flash game into Android.
What I've done is to embed the .swf of the game into an Android AIR project and export it to FLA
It worked just fine but the only problem is I need *Keys simulation*, i can't access to the game's code,but how I can add a gamepad (in the left) where it simulates arrow keys (or QSWD), and an other 4 keys that simulate "E","Q","C","G"."X
[example of how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvF70.png)"
My other problems with this is :

1. Everytime I open a level in this game (Plazma Burst2) it removes every instance I've added into the fla file
   Any help will be appreciated
   [.fla source](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/694922680046190662/801797031710425098/game.fla)

Comment: You're not making sense... _"It removes every instance I've added into the FLA"_  Are you saying the game closes itself whenever you start a level? Do you think it's a form of copy protection? Or maybe it's a genuine error (_eg:_ Using the option "Debug Movie" instead of "Test Movie", do you see errors leading to game's SWF closing)?... Anyways if it doesn't work, then why say _"It worked just fine but the only problem is I need Keys simulation"_???

Comment: @VC.One It deleted my symbols but the embedded swf works fine

Comment: @VC.One the game works fine basically, but I need buttons, I tried to add buttons but when the game starts the buttons gets deleted, understand?